# Infinite API calls on changing state in callback

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, treeview

I am trying to load data from an API to treeview (material-UI). If the data is static, then everything is fine but if I use the API in callback it triggers unlimited calls...

```js
const getTreeItemsFromData = (treeItems) => {
  //e.stoppropagation();
  return treeItems.map((treeItemData) => {
    let children = undefined;
    if (treeItemData.children && treeItemData.children.length > 0) {
      children = getTreeItemsFromData(treeItemData.children);
    }
    return (
      <TreeItem
        key={treeItemData.id}
        nodeId={treeItemData.id}
        label={treeItemData.name}
        children={children}
      />
    );
  });
};

export default function UpdateFieldObservations({
  formdata,
  handleChangeParent
}) {
  const [matrixData, setMarixData] = useState([]);

  const airdata = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Soil Vapour",
      children: [
        {
          id: 11,
          name: "Grab Sample"
        },
        {
          id: 12,
          name: "Insitu Meter Reading"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  console.log("Call API with matrixId : " + form.matrixId);
  axiosInstance
    .get("/observations/" + form.matrixId, {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Error: " + err);
    });

  return (
    <>
      <TreeView
        className={classes.root}
        defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
        onNodeSelect={handleNodeSelected}
      >
        {getTreeItemsFromData(airdata)}
      </TreeView>
    </>
  );
}
```

now if I add under

> console.log(res)
>
> setMarixData(res);

It starts with unlimited API calls..What am I doing wrong and how best to load this data to the tree instead of **airdata**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const getTreeItemsFromData = (treeItems) => {
  //e.stoppropagation();
  return treeItems.map((treeItemData) => {
    let children = undefined;
    if (treeItemData.children && treeItemData.children.length > 0) {
      children = getTreeItemsFromData(treeItemData.children);
    }
    return (
      <TreeItem
        key={treeItemData.id}
        nodeId={treeItemData.id}
        label={treeItemData.name}
        children={children}
      />
    );
  });
};

export default function UpdateFieldObservations({
  formdata,
  handleChangeParent
}) {
  const [matrixData, setMarixData] = useState([]);

  const airdata = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Soil Vapour",
      children: [
        {
          id: 11,
          name: "Grab Sample"
        },
        {
          id: 12,
          name: "Insitu Meter Reading"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  console.log("Call API with matrixId : " + form.matrixId);
  useEffect(()=>{
  axiosInstance
    .get("/observations/" + form.matrixId, {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      setMatrixData(res)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Error: " + err);
    });
  },[])

  return (
    <>
      <TreeView
        className={classes.root}
        defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
        onNodeSelect={handleNodeSelected}
      >
        {getTreeItemsFromData(airdata)}
      </TreeView>
    </>
  );
}
```

You need to fetch the API inside useEffect. If you set a state after the API call it triggers component rerendering then the API will be called again, hence it results in infinite API calls

Comment: Thanks Hari, how can i replace airdata with matrixData?

Comment: Didn't get the context

Comment: that should be separate thread..so all good..thanks!